# Create batch to add firewall rules

Tags: netsh

Is there anyway to create a batch to run the following codes ? I made the batch file but not able to get the job done.

```
    :Allow IPV4 Ping
    netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V4 echo request" 
    protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow
    Echo %errorlevel%
    Pause

    :Allow IPV6 Ping
    netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V6 echo request" 
    protocol=icmpv6:8,any dir=in action=allow
    Echo %errorlevel%
    Pause
    netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all
    Pause
```

Comment: Just to be clear. Is the script not adding the firewall rules? Or are the firewall rules added but it's somehow still not working?

Comment: New PC set up but unable to ping it after Windows OS installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the existing rule, no need use "add rule"

windows 10:
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)" new enable=yes